# Hadoop 2.2.0 Installation Error

Tags: hadoop, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 on my computer (OSX 10.9.3).

I have configured the relevant files and when I type `hadoop version` I get

```
Hadoop 2.2.0
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
This command was run using /Users/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-   
common-2.2.0.jar
```

so I believe this means that Hadoop has been installed successfully.

However, when I test run

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-    
distributedshell-2.2.0.jar org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.Client -- 
jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar -
-shell_command date --num_containers 2 --master_memory 1024
```

(by the way if you are wondering the above code means: "With this command we are telling hadoop to run the Client class in the hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar, passing it the jar containing the definition of the ApplicationMaster (the same jar), the shell command to run in each of the hosts (date), the number of containers to spawn (2) and the memory used by the ApplicationMaster (1024MB). The value of 1024 was set empirically by trying to run the program several times until it stopped failing due to the ApplicationMaster using more memory than that which had been allocated to it." according to the instructions I am following.)

I get the following error:

```
ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /user/hadoop/DistributedShell/1/AppMaster.jar
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File  
/user/hadoop/DistributedShell/1/AppMaster.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead 
of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in 
this operation.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Please forgive the stupid question, but is hadoop running ?

Comment: Forgive the stupid reply, but how can I tell? I think the instructions say that the code above is supposed to get hadoop running, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's not enough. You have to format the namenode (`bin/hdfs namenode-format`) and launch the daemons (`sbin/start-dfs` and `sbin/start-yarn`).

Comment: I used `$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format`, `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`, `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`, `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager`, `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager`. I got this warning: WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable. I don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: That's normal. If you want to avoid this warning, you'll have to build hadoop for your platform, but as far as I know, there should be no troubles with the standart distribution.

Comment: So the warning probably has nothing to do with the error I'm getting?

Comment: Also, I am getting this message: "SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Macintosh.local/192.168.0.107" when I run `$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format`. Does this mean that namenode isn't even running?

Comment: You must first format the namenode then run it.

Comment: Oh I understood it as `$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format` formats the namenode. Is there something else I'm supposed to do before I enter the `$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format` command?

Comment: You have to configure your cluster (via core-site.xml and such).

Comment: Oh OK I'll check those files again. Thanks for all the help!